# How come I can't "cd" to a folder in subprocess.call?

Tags: python, powershell

I try to cd into a folder using subprocess.call(I want to run a command in that folder) the echo is to keep the power-shell window open.

```
subprocess.call([
            "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",  
            "cd C:\dev\git-sites\Babyshop",
            "echo 'test'"
        ])
```

When I try to run this I see a red error message flashing before the window closes.

How can I keep the powershell open or get the output from it?
How come it doesn't work?

Comment: use Popen and communicate

Answer (score 2):

The list you are giving to `call()` as the parameter is not a list of commands to execute. It is the command and its arguments. You can do only one command call per `call()`.

Comment: Kristoffer: Perhaps you could try:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -command {start-transcript -path C:\temp\log.txt; cd C:\dev\git-sites\Babyshop; stop-transcript }`
you can generally add additional Powershell commands inside the script block just by separating them with the ;
The transcript output would let you see the output without having to keep Powershell open.